# How can I update score and stars in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing a quiz app in Android Studio using java where are different types of test for the user when the user click on test_button then the quiz will start after ending of the quiz I want to update same test_button with score and stars I am putting image for better understanding (Thanks in advance )

_[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hchb6.png)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved using sharedpreference.